# Spring - Enum in RestControllers?

Tags: java, enums, spring-restcontroller

I know there are a lot of topics on this area already but none of them had a satisfying answer for me. I have the following endpoint and enum:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
   @PostMapping
   public void doStuff(@RequestParam MyEnum myEnum){
      ...
   }
}

public enum MyEnum {
   PROPERTY_A("foo"),
   PROPERTY_B("bar");

   private String name;

   MyEnum(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

I want to register a custom converter that converts the string values of foo and bar into the correct enum values of PROPERTY_A, PROPERTY_B. Something that should be easily solved with a simple @Override somewhere to hijack the standard converter that fails to convert this, yet all the answers I've seen for this question requires you to register code in three-four places which is not a satisfactory answer to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> should be easily solved with a simple `@Override` somewhere to hijack the **standard converter**

If by saying *standard converter*, you refer to the `MyEnum.valueOf(String)` method, then the answer is *you can't*.

Because method `valueOf()` is `static` and there's **no** concept of *overriding* for `static` methods in Java. And more over the flavor `valueOf(String)` is not even exists in the implicit parent class `java.lang.Enum`, it gets added by the *compiler* as well as `values()` method to every *enum* during the compilation.

In other words, you are not in control of `valueOf(String)` method by any means.

> register code in *three-four* places

Since your method `doStuff()` expects an instance of `MyEnum` and you didn't mention any other enum-classes, I assume that you are interested only in converting a string into a member of `MyEnum`. And you can achieve this by adding a single method into `MyEnum` (no need to introduce new code in multiple places):

```
public enum MyEnum {
    PROPERTY_A("foo"),
    PROPERTY_B("bar");
    
    private String name;
    
    MyEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public static MyEnum getByName(String name) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
            .filter(e -> e.name.equals(name))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(); // throw NoSuchElementException if no constant with a matching property has been found
    }
}
```

Method `getByName()` will throw `NoSuchElementException` if enum-member with the given name doesn't exist.

If you are not satisfied with such behavior, you can change the implementation. For instance, to return an optional object (which is more preferred than returning `null`):

```
public static Optional<MyEnum> getByName(String name) {
    return Arrays.stream(values())
        .filter(e -> e.name.equals(name))
        .findFirst();
}
```

Or you can use `orElse()` instead of `orElseThrow()` to return a particular *enum-constant* which would represent the absence of data, i.e. implement the [*Null-object pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern).

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer! Sadly the suggestion for using getByName() doesn't seem to be working, it still throws MethodArgumentTypeMissmatchException and when I put a breakpoint at the entry of the method it's never catches so I'm guessing Spring ignores the method.

Comment: @DavidS This exception which is coming from spring indicates that there's a problem with resolving method arguments inside a controller.

Comment: @DavidS The signature of `doStuff()` needs to be changed to parse the enum "manually". Spring is not aware that it needs use `getByName()` like any other custom method. Can you make the argument to be a `String` instead of enum? And then parse the string using `getByName()`.